# Getting only half results from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, localhost

I am having issue with PHP returning only half number of records in server but all on localhost. Below is the code snippet.

```
$customersSQL = "SELECT * FROM oneoff_donations_stripe WHERE customer_email='". $_SESSION["loginEmail"] ."'";
$customers = $conn->query($customersSQL);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try the same query on both localhost and server with a desktop client like the `mysql` command line or HeidiSQL?

Comment: How are your fetching the results ? What is the result of the num_rows() ?

Comment: I have almost 45K records in the database however I am getting only about 28K records with this query on the server but localhost is returning 45K records. @Syscall

Comment: @O. Jones, I am getting all records on the database using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @Anil That didn't answer my questions.

Comment: Is the database encoding the same on the server? The issuse can be case-sensitivness of the encoding.

Comment: I am using fetch_assoc() to fetch records. @Syscall.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It was caused by SELECT statement breaking execution of UPDATE statement. I fixed that problem by making sure that SELECT happens after UPDATE has finished executing. I hope it helps in some way. Cheers.

Comment: I don't have any update statement before select

Comment: Do you have ANY other statement that might interfere with your statement? If not then I would say your problem is not code related.